# Avoid inserting duplicate data in csv with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I store data into a csv file by this:

```
$out = fopen('wpo_stock.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($out, array($order_id,$product_id,$product_name,$product_quantity, $regular_price));
fclose($out);
```

That stores my data in csv perfectly.
The problem is: Every time the page refreshed, it keeps inserting duplicated datas in the csv file.
How can I avoid inserting duplicated data by order_id (order_id is a unique value in my project)?

**Code Updated :**

```
$handle = fopen('wpo_stock.csv', 'r');
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE) {
if($data[0] != $order_id){
$out = fopen('wpo_stock.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($out, array($order_id,$product_id,$product_name,$product_quantity, $regular_price));
} break;
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to override your data all the time when a page refreshes. In that case, you should open your file like this `$out = fopen('wpo_stock.csv', 'w');`.

But if you are trying to append new data, then you need to read all data from your file and compare with a new one.

Comment: Thanks for answering the [a] is correct because I want append. Exactly, I need to compare new data, but I don't know how to compare csv order_id  column  with my existing array order_id and if order_id already existing in my csv file don't write them again.

Comment: Read all data from your current CSV file and loop it. Inside loop check if any order IDs exists in a new data array.

Comment: As you can see in above, I update my code with the way you explain, but now that's not working at all. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Keep a separate array of "order ids that i've already processed".

Comment: IvanIvan ,thanks for answering but, I don't get your point can you explain more and specifically?

Comment: Okay, now my code is working but its only search the first line.